# catching another value in same <tr in web scraping vba

Tags: html, vba, selenium-webdriver, xpath

What I try to do. I have a team name, I want to scrape from table the WIN stats of that team.
What I do, I go through every //tr//span element in table, with if condition try to catch if the team name is in table, if yes, then inside loop, I want to goBack with Selenium xPath go to parent element (..). I wonder how in other way way I can achieve it. Maybe only way is bringing all data in <td inside list, then search inside list not inside HTML. As it seems impossible to go back from element (in my situation <span) you found team name, then going back and taking the 6 th <td value of that same <tr

```
Sub nbaScrape_Stats()

    Dim driver As WebDriver
    Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.WebDriver")
    
    Dim xUrl As String
    xUrl = "https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional"
        driver.Start "chrome", xUrl
        
        driver.Get "/", 10000
        
        Dim we_to_click As WebElement
        'https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional?sort=W_PCT&dir=-1&Season=2021-22&SeasonType=Regular+Season&LastNGames=1/
        Set we_to_click = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""onetrust-accept-btn-handler""]")
        Debug.Print driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""onetrust-accept-btn-handler""]").Text, "-date:-", Now()
        we_to_click.Click
        driver.Wait 1000

        Set we_to_click = driver.FindElementByXPath("//section[1]/div/div/div[4]/label/div/select/optgroup[1]/option[1]")
        Debug.Print driver.FindElementByXPath("//section[1]/div/div/div[4]/label/div/select/optgroup[1]/option[1]").Text, "-date:-", Now()
        we_to_click.Click 'run-time error sometimes
        
        Dim wr_to_xl As WebElements
        Set wr_to_xl = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//tbody/tr//span") 'LINE: array of <span elements (1)
        
        i = 1
        For Each element In wr_to_xl
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = element.Text
                If ActiveSheet.[C3].Value = element.Text Then 'team name if equals
                Set element_main = element.FindElementByXPath("//tbody/tr//span/..") '(2)
                'line below, I want to catch the sixth <td of that row/team's win streak
                    Debug.Print element_main.FindElementByXPath("//table/tbody/tr/td[6]").Text, "<-", element.Text, "-match:-", Now()
                End If
            i = i + 1
        Next
        
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
        driver.Quit
End Sub
```

> https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional

First I search for team name, then I took the stats like (WIN% , game played)
[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me, what you want

Comment: Have you launched this macro? If so, it will be easy for me go from there. You see the table of team names, I want to take the team by search and its statistics in that row. My problem is, when get team name with element.text, I then cannot take other values from that element which are inside other <td> tag names

Comment: Looks like you need to use **relative** XPath: `element.FindElementByXPath(".//tbody/tr//span/..")` instead of `element.FindElementByXPath("//tbody/tr//span/..")` etc.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an example of what output you want because I'm not sure I understand what data you want to extract. Do you want to extract the 6th cell of the table row whose second cell matches the name of a particular team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get the value of win% with xpath:

```
//table//span[text()='Phoenix Suns']/../../../..//td[6]
```

You said you already have the name, right? Then only get the text of that Xpath and you will get the Win%.

If you want some other column, only change the 6 by the number of column you want.